# yfinance api not working - receiving thread error

Tags: python, yfinance

I was trying to run some code that I was able to run in the past with the following error. I tried to uninstalling yfinance and installing it again, upgrading yfinance, and the solution in the following link:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 169, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 181, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 152, in history
    data = self.session.get(
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

Already tried this solutions as well:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade yfinance
```

As well as solution from this link:

https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/

Comment: This may be a dumb question but everything does work internet wise, right? (I mean if the program cannot connect to the API then it might have this error)

Comment: Hello, that was my first intuition as well. Wasn't sure if it was my wifi but I've tried connecting to different wifi, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Install this version https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/